# Facebook post/video URL regex

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook

I'm trying to distinguish between whether a given Facebook URL is a post or a video.

Luckily, [Facebook lists the possible URLs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed-endpoints) for both posts and videos:

> Posts:
>
> - https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}/posts/{post-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/{username}/posts/{post-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/{username}/activity/{activity-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={photo-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/photos/{photo-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid={post-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/media/set?set={set-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/questions/{question-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/notes/{username}/{note-url}/{note-id}>
>
> Videos:
>
> - https://www.facebook.com/{page-name}/videos/{video-id}/>
> - https://www.facebook.com/{username}/videos/{video-id}/>
> - https://www.facebook.com/video.php?id={video-id}>
> - https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v={video-id}>

However, I have no idea how to use regex to check if a given URL matches one of the above URLs.

I've started a regex101 page, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

https://regex101.com/r/M7RTVP/2

Comment: @Stargateur JavaScript

Comment: I ask again why do you need a regex? What is your purpose? We could really help you much better if you say it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Posts](https://regex101.com/r/TvJ7Uh/2): `/^https:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/(photo(\.php|s)|permalink\.php|media|questions|notes|[^\/]+\/(activity|posts))[\/?].*$/gm`

[Videos](https://regex101.com/r/DTv02n/2): `/^https:\/\/www\.facebook\.com\/([^\/?].+\/)?video(s|\.php)[\/?].*$/gm`

Comment: Couple problems. `page-name` and `username` are placements, i.e. `username` can be any user's username, like `bob` or `sammy`. Same with `page-name` and `note-url`.

Comment: @user7260348 Ah, yes. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple substring search would be enough for these, but these would work:

Posts: `(?:post|activity|photo|media|questions|note|story)`

Videos: `video`